# Compare Validator Issue Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a created a compare validtaor for comparing date to and from. It works fine but when I try to hit "search" button it triggers that button and page errors out. I have other compare validators too but they do not trigger search button. I want the display to be locked down till it validates.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator3" runat="server" CssClass="dark"  ControlToCompare="wdpFrom" ControlToValidate="wdpTo" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date" Text ="To date must be greater than From date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

I have this validator for datatype check which works fine

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" 

Operator="DataTypeCheck" 

Type="Integer"

ControlToValidate="txtInvPos" 

Text="Inventory Position ID can only be Integer" CssClass="dark" ErrorMessage="Inventory Position ID can only be Integer" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#FF3300" SetFocusOnError="True" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue in the "search" method I was calling
comparevalidator2.validation() got rid of it and works fine now.